# SSO With the New Azure Portal

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

I've found a number of step by step instructions on setting up Single Sign On (SSO) working with the Azure AD.  I want to use AD to authenticate users to access an external web site.  In fact I got one working from GitHub a few years ago.  But, I don't find any information on doing SSO with the new Azure portal.  I can't find any SSO settings there.  Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you must use the classic portal to create a new Active Directory application/ configure SSO. This ability will be added to the Azure portal in a later release. You can use the portal to assign the application to a role. You can also perform these steps through Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI. For more information about using PowerShell or CLI with the service principal, see [Authenticating a service principal with Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/).

[Source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/)

Comment: Ken, I found out about the need to use the "classic portal" to setup SSO by trial and error, but thank you for confirming that.  I have that setup done.  Now I need to setup an SSL cert.  Microsoft gave me some instructions, but it seems rather cumbersome.  You'd think there would be an easier way to do this.  Here what they gave me:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/